# How to remove a certain time period from a dataframe with timestamp index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that is something like this:

```
Datetime             Open   Low/Open  Close/Open  Tar

1998-01-30 15:30:00  68.02  0.997501    0.999706    0
1998-01-30 15:45:00  67.91  0.998086    1.000736    0
1998-01-30 16:00:00  67.96  0.998676    1.000589    0
1998-01-30 16:15:00  67.96  1.000000    1.000000    0
```

the timestamp is 24 hours, however, I only want the data points that have index between 9:30:00 to 16:00:00. How do I remove all the data points outside of what I need?

Answer (score 1):

The `.dt` suffix of any datetime column has array-friendly routines.

```
import datetime

df[(df.Datetime.dt.time >= datetime.time(9, 30)) &
   (df.Datetime.dt.time <= datetime.time(16, 0))]
```

From your sample, I get:

```
             Datetime   Open  Low/Open  Close/Open  Tar
0 1998-01-30 15:30:00  68.02  0.997501    0.999706    0
1 1998-01-30 15:45:00  67.91  0.998086    1.000736    0
2 1998-01-30 16:00:00  67.96  0.998676    1.000589    0
```

Comment: the Datetime column is my index, is there a quick way to apply this to the index?